# state boolean not flipping back to false with .some React Apollo GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have some functions which handle a user following and unfollowing another user.

```
  const handleFollowUser = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await followUser({
        variables: {
          followedByUserId: Number(state.currentUser.id),
          followingUserId: Number(postFromUser.id)
        }
      })
      if (data) {
        refetchFollowers()
        checkIsFollowing()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  const handleUnfollowUser = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await unfollowUser({
        variables: {
          userId: Number(state.currentUser.id),
          userIdToUnfollow: Number(postFromUser.id)
        }
      })
      if (data) {
        refetchFollowers()
        checkIsFollowing()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

`checkIsFollowing` searches a users followers list and checks if the current user ID in there. This always works properly on page load.

```
  const checkIsFollowing = () => {
    followersData?.getAllUserFollowers.some((follower) => {
      setIsFollowing(follower.id === state.currentUser.id)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (followersData) {
      checkIsFollowing()
    }
  }, [followersData])
```

The problem im having is when I unfollow a user the boolean `isFollowing` is not flipping back to false. It flips properly when I follow the user initially but not if I unfollow them. Even though `followersData?.getAllUserFollowers` shows an empty array after `refetchFollowers` runs

Comment: It looks like you've misunderstood `some()`. The callback passed to `some()` should return a boolean, if true `some` terminates and returns true. You appear to be using it simply as a curious `forEach`.

Comment: @pilchard does ```.some()``` not run a condition test on an array and return a boolean if one of the elements passes the test?

Comment: yes, but you haven't given it a test, you're calling `setIsFollowing` on each iteration and never returning anything to `some()` so it will always return `false`

Comment: @pilchard but it is returning  true when I follow a user

Comment: Yes, because on one of those iterations it sets it correctly, but it will call `setIsFollowing` for ***every*** follower in the array. (as I said, you're using it as a `forEach`). I think you want `setIsFollowing(followersData?.getAllUserFollowers.some((follower) => follower.id === state.currentUser.id));`. Set it to the return value of `some()` having tested each follower.id against state.currentUser.id.

Answer (score 0):

Let's wrap the two async method within useCallback of react, remove the checkIsFollowing() call from within these two async as it is being called from useEffect, and adding dependency to these methods:

```
const handleFollowUser = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await followUser({
        variables: {
          followedByUserId: Number(state.currentUser.id),
          followingUserId: Number(postFromUser.id)
        }
      })
      if (data) {
        //When you receive data, you should set followersData state here. Like, setFollowersData(data). Please, make sure that you have done it properly.
        refetchFollowers()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  },[state.currentUser.id, postFromUser.id])

  const handleUnfollowUser = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await unfollowUser({
        variables: {
          userId: Number(state.currentUser.id),
          userIdToUnfollow: Number(postFromUser.id)
        }
      })
      if (data) {
        refetchFollowers()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }, [state.currentUser.id, postFromUser.id])
```

After that, let's modify the dependency of useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (followersData) {
      checkIsFollowing()
    }
  }, [followersData, handleFollowUser, handleUnfollowUser])
```

And, as pilchard said in his comment, you should concentrate on your checkIsFollowing method if it returns correctly.

Comment: Even if these are functional optimizations you haven't addressed the question at all, which is rooted in a misunderstanding of the use of `some()`. See my comments above. The only thing you didn't refactor was the function that had the actual error in it.

Comment: I have seen that you have already mentioned that in the comments of the question. And, Ben is replying to that comment. So, it seems he would be able to figure it out from you.

Comment: If you are posting an answer, then you need to address the question asked. Further optimazations can be mentioned, but should not overshadow the actual answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. Will try to follow next time. I thought it would be redundant to mention about that part since you have already mentioned.